# How to get confidence interval of high standard deviation time-based data?

Tags: python, scipy, confidence-interval, data-fitting

I'm working with an analysis of some latencies (in seconds). My idea is to find my confidence interval where 95% of my results fit, so I can have some idea of the PDF.

By sight, the more common latencies I get are under 30 seconds, but eventually there are some problems in the system which can give me up to 25 minutes. This doesn't concern me, since the cadency in which the system works is around 1h per cycle.

My point is that, working with times that have that much difference, my confidence interval seems "not fair". Here is an example of a confidence interval I got using standard deviation:

[image: confidence interval using standard deviation (from scipy stats)]

My idea is to find the best fit PDF, get its parameters and then use this alone to find my confidence interval. I tested a few diferent distributions and actually got JohnsonSU and the best fit for this data. Here it is:

[image: Best Fit PDF to my data]

Is it possible for me to use the parameters of JohnsonSU alone, without using my data, so I can find an acceptable confidence interval?

Comment: I believe this is not the best place to be asking this, try at cross validated!

Comment: Thanks, @CeliusStingher. It's posted there for some time, but no answers so far.

Answer (score 0):

You can get and interval of confidence by the expression:

(mean-(std/sqrt(n)),mean+(std/sqrt(n))). If your distribution is standad and you know the population std.

Othewrwise you'll need to check a specific expression that suits your distribution.

Comment: Hi, Daladier! Thanks for your answer. This is how I'm getting the green interval on the first image. The problem with this is that my few "high seconds data" are pulling this interval to a higher value. That's why I'd like to know if, from the parameters of my pdf, I can get a nice confidence interval. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can try an KS Test to check if your distribution is a normal. If not, you can try another confidence interval for your data.